# Pig register jar, file does not exist error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm using Hortonworks sandbox and trying to run a simple pig script. There appear to be annoying error related to "file does not exist".

Below is the script:

```
REGISTER '/piggybank.jar';

inp = load '/my.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage..
```

> ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File does not exist:
>   hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/udfs/ '/piggybank.jar'

However, my jar is present at the root(/) and I have given proper permission as well. Don't know why the path is pointing to **/tmp/udfs**....

Can anyone provide some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Do not place the path within quotes. Also provide full URI of the Jar file location.

```
REGISTER hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/piggybank.jar;
```

Refer [REGISTER (a jar/script)](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/basic.html#register-jar).